# Discord Bot in python creating an invite link and dming it to a user

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am making a Discord Bot in Python(3.7.3) and I would like to send a dm to a user with an invite link to the server. This is my code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=config.get_config, description='Thou Holy Bot')

@bot.command(name='dm',pass_context=True)
async def dm(ctx, *, argument):
    <code here>
```

I have a discord.member.Member() class. And I would like to make an invite link to a channel(a have a channel object if that's needed) and dm it to a user. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What is your question? Please make your problem obvious in order to help. Make you sure you read [How to ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: How do you want to specify the user?  Your bot can only message people with whom it shares at least one guild that allows members to message one another.

Comment: @YoussofH I had a random kick command and I wanted to send a dm with an invite link to the random person who got kicked. I now realise thanks to Patrick Haugh that it is impossible. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @ScottBot10 Could you not re-order the process and Send the link and then kick ? So you can still PM the user before they are kicked ? Or did you want the actions to be separate ?

Comment: @Antry Yes I could but I am still unsure on how to create an invite link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who helped me I have found a solution.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', description='Bot')

@bot.command(name='dm',pass_context=True)
async def dm(ctx, *argument):
    #creating invite link
    invitelink = await ctx.channel.create_invite(max_uses=1,unique=True)
    #dming it to the person
    await ctx.author.send(invitelink)
```

Here is the documentation [create_invite documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.create_invite)

Answer (score 0):

You can merely create an invite link that never expires manually, and use said invite link in the DM you send to the person being kicked before the bot executes the kick.

Comment: I wanted a unique one every time so people couldn't reuse them. I have found a solution, but thanks though. I have answered my question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this in a cog:

```
     import discord
     from discord.ext import commands
     class Information(commands.Cog):

     def __init__(self,bot):
     self.bot = bot

     @commands.command(brief='A one time server invite',pass_context=True)
     async def serverinvite(self, ctx):
     invitelink = await ctx.channel.create_invite(max_age = 90, max_uses=1, unique=True)
     await ctx.send(invitelink)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Including information to explain what is happening in comments and/or narrative outside the code would probably be helpful to the question asker.